# Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential for ml.googleapis.com

Tags: api, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I am running this code from my laptop. I want to call a tensorlflow model which is on GCP. I try to simulate an API call from our systems to GCP.

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import requests
import json

PROJECT = 'blabla-project'
MODEL_NAME = 'blablaModelName'
MODEL_VERSION = 'blabla_version'

token=GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().get_access_token().access_token
api = 'https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{}/models/{}/versions/{}:predict' \
     .format(PROJECT, MODEL_NAME, MODEL_VERSION)
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
data = {
'instances': [
 {
    'X1':600,
    'X2':8965,
    'X3':17.93,
    'X4':23,
    'X5':52216.32776,
    'X6':144.2442343,
    'X7':0,
    'X8':0,
    'X9':0,
    'X10':0
},
{
    'X1':600,
    'X2':6965,
    'X3':17.93,
    'X4':23,
    'X5':52216.32776,
    'X6':144.2442343,
    'X7':0,
    'X8':0,
    'X9':0,
    'X10':0
},
]
}
response = requests.post(api, json=data,headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.content)
```

At each time I run the code I have this error.

```
Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
```

I am using python 3.8.3 on Windows.

Can anyone tell me where the code is broken or which authentication method should I use.

Comment: Can you [format the code in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and offer more context to get a more accurate answer?

Comment: I think that's more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **NOTE:** [OAUTH2CLIENT](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html) has been deprecated and you need to use [GOOGLE-AUTH](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default) instead.

Please find your code modified below using the latest Google OAuth library:

```
import requests
import json
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests


PROJECT = 'project-name'
MODEL_NAME = 'modelname'
MODEL_VERSION = 'version'

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only'])

api = 'https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{}/models/{}/versions/{}:predict' \
     .format(PROJECT, MODEL_NAME, MODEL_VERSION)

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
credentials.refresh(request)
token = credentials.token

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
data = {
    "instances" : [
        {
            'X1':600,...
    }
}
response = requests.post(api, json=data, headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.content)
```

Instead of using `get_application_default()` you need to use `google.auth.default` and depending on the API being called, the proper [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#ml) have to be defined in order to access the Google API’s.

I ran the same code in [Google Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell) and it works perfectly fine. The reason being: Google Cloud Shell runs on a Compute Engine VM which has an OAuth token  already created for the logged in account and saved in the local [Compute Engine VM metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity#request_signature).

As noted in the [`google.auth.default` documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default), it detects that it is running in a Compute Engine VM and automatically uses that default OAuth token located in the VM Metadata Server.

When you run the code from your local machine, you need to make your own OAuth token accessible to the code by using one of the following authentication methods:

-- Using [Service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started):

1. [Create a Service Account and download a JSON key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account).
2. Set the [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable) environment variable to the path of the downloaded service account key file (JSON).
3. The same [`google.auth.default` documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default) code you use also checks this special environment variable for the set JSON OAuth token and uses it automatically.

-- **OR** using a [User account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#webserver):

1. This can be achieved by running the [following command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) to generate the token:

   `gcloud auth application-default login`
2. Then remove the `google.auth.default` code and replace it with the output from the [following command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token) instead:

   `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

Comment: Thank you Ivana, do I need to set the variable in my code? Because the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENDTIALS is already created on my system.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - GCP's Python docs for this still mention the (now deprecated) oauth2client library and had me chasing my tail just like the OP: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/sslCertificates/insert#examples ...I've left them feedback on that page so they can get it updated.